# Why does PhpStorm keep opening Xdebug sessions for me all the time

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

When I use PhpStorm and turn on the server to connect with Xdebug, it happens to me that the debug starts by itself even though I haven't requested it and I can't figure out why.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Among other things, when I close PhpStorm it asks me if I want to close a session on `stdin`.

Comment: Maybe some misconfiguration of stdin made by xdebug?

Answer (score 1):

To find out why Xdebug makes a connection, make a log file!

You do that by setting `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log`, and also `xdebug.log_level=10` in `php.ini`, or another INI file that Xdebug uses.

You can find out which ones by using `php --ini` on the command line, or using `phpinfo()` in a PHP page.

Don't forget to restart the web server when you modify an INI file.

In the log file that Xdebug creates, you will be able to see which triggers are active, and to which host/port Xdebug is trying to connect.